# how to read files from directory using for loop using php

Tags: php

i want to read images using loop in side my images-folder as images name 
        will be from 1.jpg to 100.jpg  and here i am using array to get images

```
$files = array("images-folder/1.jpg","images-folder/2.jpg"); /*Image array*/
```

i am reading images in .jpg extension inside my images folder (images-
         folder) 
         and downloading them in zip file .so far it is working with these line 
         of codes
         $files = array("images-folder/1.jpg","images-folder/2.jpg"); /*Image 
         array*/

```
create new zip opbject
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

     $tmp_file = tempnam('.',''); /*create a temp file & open it*/
     $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

     # loop through each file
     foreach($files as $file){

       # download file
         $download_file = file_get_contents($file);        
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);/*add it to the zip*/
     }

        # close zip
        $zip->close();/*send the file to the browser as a download*/

        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        readfile($tmp_file);
        echo($file);
```

Comment: So, if it is working, what is your question?

Comment: $files = array("images-folder/1.jpg","images-folder/2.jpg"); 
here i have to pass each image name in side an array 
but i want to pass values using loop as my image array will be from 1 to 100.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include just the part where you are stuck. Are you looking for a way to list the files in a directory, or how to filter that list to a certain pattern of file name? If so, we don't need to know about zip files. Are you looking for a way to generate strings containing numbers 1 to 100 in an array or loop without writing them by hand? If so, we don't even need to know that they're file names. Breaking the problem down in this way will help you search for existing answers and documentation, and help us understand how to help you if you still can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your array with filenames like this:

```
$files = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; ++$i) {
   $files[] = "images-folder/$i.jpg";
}
```

Just loop over all the numbers and store them in an array.